# broken pipe when tar extracted from stdin buffer

Tags: pipe, tar, buffer

I am restoring files from a tar archive on an LTO-7 tape to a locally mounted network share. If I directly restore to the share it runs very slowly (90 MB/s). When I use an additional buffer I get the maximum throughput of 280 MB/s. However I get a broken pipe warning:

```
mbuffer -s 1M -m 2G -i /dev/st0 | tar -xf -
mbuffer: warning: error during output to <stdout>: Broken pipe
```

Note that the tar archive was originally written with a blocking factor of 2048 (i.e. 1MB block size)

I guess this means that tar is exiting before it has received all the data (maybe the buffer became temporarily empty and tar thought the data is over?).

1. How do I get around this? i.e. How do I ensure tar waits for all the data to be received from the buffer?
2. Why is buffering actually needed in the first place? The connection is 10G, the destination disk is a very fast RAID. What is the underlying reason that causes the slowdown?

**EDIT 02/07/2020**

I added the blocking factor to the tar command and the warning doesn't come.

```
mbuffer -s 1M -m 2G -i /dev/st0 | tar -x -b 2048 -f -
```

But I'd still like to know why I get a broken pipe warning if this is not specified.

Comment: Why do you use such a strange program instead of using  a better tar implementation? `star` includes a `FIFO` buffer since 30 years and does not need to waste CPU cycles while reading from a pipe.

Comment: i tried star fifo but I get memory allocation / segmentation errors if I specify a fifo size greater than 1g

Comment: There is no need for a huge FIFO. It just needs to be large enough to keep the I/O running at all time.

Comment: There was a report to a `star` bug related t the fifo size yesterday that has been fixed yesterday and will be published soon. I now see, that report was from you, so you'll get a patch this day... If you see problems with more than 1g already, there is a bug in your OS. `star fs=2000m ...` works without problems and much more will work after the fix. Note that the FIFO is 30 years old, nobody had that amount of RAM 30 years ago and nobody reported the problem before.

Answer (score -1):

Your error message has a simple reason: the tar implementation you used did not read all data befre calling `exit()`.

This is caused (as you did already find out yourself) by the fact that you did not tell it the real tape block size.

A typical tape, except for QIC cartriges is blocked and for higher performance, it is recommended to use a large block size. A block size > 126 kB is not recommended for exchange with other people but for a backup, it is OK to use 1MB as block size.

`TAR` on the other side is also specified as working block oriented, with a default block size of 10kB.

The `EOF` definiton for a `TAR` archive is two zeroed 512 blocks directly after the last file (which is where a new `tar` header is expected.

After that EOF indication, archive prcessing stops and unless these two zeroed blocks by chance appear in the last 10 kB of the tape data, there is unread input and this is why you get a broken pipe message.

If you use `star`, the FIFO is inside `tar` and as a result, the **tape read code** and the `tar` archive processing always have the same idea of the tape block size. Besides the fact that `star` is more effective in being fast, this avoids the problem that not all input data is consumed from a `tar archive`.

BTW: for optimal streaming, a FIFO buffer size is recommended that lasts for 10-30 seconds of data with the maximum tape speed. Until `star` has been completely enhanced to support a larger FIFO, I recommend you to call:

```
star fs=2000m ...
```

Note: `-fifo` is the default in `star` since 30 years. Also note that options like `-shm` are not recommended in special on Linux where the amount of memory with this facility is limited.

`star` is definitely faster than any other `tar` implementation. Keep however in mind, that if you are using a `COW` filesystem like `ZFS` or if your OS has a slow kernel buffering implementation, it is recommended for speed to disable `fsync()` calls via `-no-fsync` when in extract mode. This makes `star` as "unreliable" as other `tar` implementations ;-) by not being able to know whether a file is been safe on the background storage, but this speeds up extraction by a factor of 4 on `ZFS` or a tradidional filesyste with bad buffereing. `ZFS` however does not implement bad buffering, but just is only able to grant a specific  filesystem state at a high expense.